# Writing to CSV, getting "Error: need to escape" for a blank string

Tags: python, csv

I am probably going to feel very dumb when someone spots what I'm doing wrong here, but I am finding myself unable to defeat what looks like it should be a simple error.

I am writing some data to a CSV with Python. One of the things I want to write is a `list` of integers. I `join` the list into a string before writing it to the file:

```
with open('publishers.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, delimiter='|', quotechar='')
    for item in big_list_of_objects:
        description = item.description
        number_list = item.number_list
        formatted_numbers = "-".join(number_list)
        writer.writerow([
            description,
            formatted_numbers
            ])
```

`number_list` may have anywhere from zero to a whole bunch of numbers in it. If it's an empty list, the `join` just sets `formatted_numbers` equal to a blank string. If it's not an empty list, I get a string made of up integers connected by hyphens.

```
number_list = [1,2,34,12]
formatted_numbers = '1-2-34-12'

number_list = []
formatted_numbers = ''
```

That's the idea, anyway. In reality, what happens is the first five rows write successfully then I get:

```
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/path/path/path.py", line 500, in offending_function
    formatted_numbers
Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set
```

Now in this particular situation, the first five rows that write successfully have an empty `number_list`. The row that consistently crashes *also* has an empty `number_list`. There is nothing weird about the value being written immediately before or after `number_list` on this row. And there is nothing weird about the `formatted_numbers` being written when this error crops up - I tossed in a `print` statement to debug, and it's just an empty string like the five before it.

Can anyone help me figure out where I might be going wrong here?

---

Edit: I have added these print statements:

```
with open('publishers.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, delimiter='|', quotechar='')
    for item in big_list_of_objects:
        description = item.description
        print "Description for %r is %r" % (item,description)
        number_list = item.number_list
        print "Now formatting %r for %r" % (number_list,item)
        formatted_numbers = "-".join(number_list)
        print repr(formatted_numbers)
        writer.writerow([
            description,
            formatted_numbers
            ])
```

The result:

```
Description for 'p89' is u''
Now formatting '' for 'p89'
''
Description for 'p88' is u''
Now formatting '' for 'p88'
''
Description for 'p83' is u''
Now formatting '' for 'p83'
''
Description for 'p82' is u'in-tr-t91411'
Now formatting '' for 'p82'
''
Description for 'p81' is u''
Now formatting '' for 'p81'
''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/path/path/path.py", line 501, in offending_function
    formatted_numbers
Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set
```

`p81` is not written to the CSV - this is where the crash occurs. However, as you can see, `print repr(formatted_numbers)` reveals it to be a blank string identical to those before it. There is no `description` for item `p81` (just a blank string), but there *is* a `description` for the item preceding it.

Comment: Exactly which line do you get that error on?

Comment: The error hits on the line where `formatted_numbers` is fed into `writer.writerow()`. I have edited the first code snippet to reflect the formatting I'm using on my end, the traceback should make more sense now.

Comment: can you print out the description of the row when the error occurs?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The issue is most probably occuring because your `description` has `|` in it, which is the delimiter for your csv as well. Hence, csv is trying to escape it, but cannot since no `csv.escapechar`s are set. Example to show same issue in my computer -

```
>>> description = 'asda|sd'
>>> formatted_numbers = ''
>>> with open('a.csv','w') as f:
...     writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, delimiter='|', quotechar='')
...     writer.writerow([
...             description,
...             formatted_numbers
...             ])
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
_csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set
```

One fix would be to provide an escapechar so that it can be escaped. Example -

```
writer = csv.writer(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, delimiter='|', quotechar='',escapechar='\\')    #Or any other appropriate escapechar
```

Or another fix would be to remove the `|` in the description before trying to write it, if you do not really need it in the description field -

```
description = description.replace('|','')
```

Or you can quote all the fields , by using `csv.QUOTE_ALL` instead of `csv.QUOTE_NONE` as provide a valid `quotechar` .

Comment: Added some print statements to the script and edited in the results. There isn't a pipe character in any of the surrounding fields.

Comment: Try setting the escapechar to something , like I did in my example, let the complete csv get written out, and then check what was written out with an escape char?

Comment: Whew okay, I now understand what the problem is. Someone snuck a carriage return into one of these descriptions and it was making the encoding very unhappy. Adding `.encode('utf-8')` to the affected field did the trick. I found this thanks to your suggestion of adding an escape character and examining the CSV. I am very new to the CSV module and didn't think about that. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much. I was with a different problem: my csv files were saving with double quote whenever I had quote in my string. And now it's fixed. :)

Comment: Note: TypeError: "escapechar" must be a 1-character string, so '\\' will not work.

Comment: '\\' is a single character (backslash). It is escaped that is why it appears twice.

Answer (score 0):

The only working solution for writing NUL byte is to set `escapechar`.

This is not working:

```py
import csv
with open('test.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, quotechar='"')
    writer.writerow(['\0'])
```

Even when you use `escapechar` while writing it can not be read:

```
with open('test.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, escapechar='\\')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)

Error: line contains NUL
```