# Python - Export Oracle Table to CSV Error

Tags: python, oracle

I have a Python script which converts Oracle table to CSV:

```
import sys
import csv
import cx_Oracle
import time
from datetime import timedelta
start_time = time.monotonic()
table_name = sys.argv[1]
csv_file_name = table_name + ".csv"
sql_query = "SELECT * FROM " + table_name
con = cx_Oracle.connect('abc/password@ec2-1-111-11-111.compute-1.amazonaws.com/orcl')
cursor = con.cursor()
csv_file = open(csv_file_name, "w")
writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', lineterminator="\n", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
r = cursor.execute(sql_query)
for row in cursor:
    writer.writerow(row)
cursor.close()
con.close()
csv_file.close()
end_time = time.monotonic()
print(timedelta(seconds=end_time - start_time))
```

When I run:

```
python3 export-csv.py AUTHOR
```

It gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "export-csv.py", line 16, in <module>
    writer.writerow(row)
_csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set
```

How to fix this issue? Also, how can I get the column names of Oracle table included in the CSV file?

Comment: Your code works for me when I try it on something like USER_TABLES. The error probably comes from the data you have in your table. Is there any LOB, or string columns containing special characters?

Comment: My data has , I think in one of the column

Comment: So, you need to provide an escape char, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32107790/writing-to-csv-getting-error-need-to-escape-for-a-blank-string